# Объекты в js

Tags: ооп, javascript

Только начал практиковать ООП в js.
Насколько корректна подобная запись?

```
mainObj = {
    childObj: {
        obj: function() {функция},
        obj2: function(e) {функция2}
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректна, только последнюю запятую лучше убрать.

Comment: "Насколько корректна"?
какие аналоги есть?

Comment: корректна настолько насколько есть необходимость в такой конструкции, не больше не меньше....

Comment: <a href="http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object">ООП в JavaScript</a>